# Better than Flickr for albums hierarchy

Tags: flickr, file-management, sharing

Is any of the other major photosharing sites better than Flickr for the albums hierarchy? I mean the possibility to define a depth of more than two... If I'm not mistaken in flickr you can only define Collections and then Albums in those Collections, but you can't get any deeper.

Comment: Out of curiosity what is your organizational use case?

Comment: I like to have my images separated by year, for example.

Comment: You can also tag your images by year, giving a way to look at them across that axis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flickr does allow a collection to contain either sets, or other collections, giving you that hierarchy

Comment: Nice, I didn't notice this. I had some sets in a collection and it didn't let me add another collection inside... Thanks.

Comment: @Carles I found it "less than obvious" that a collection could only contain one type of thing, but I do do this myself with a few collections

Comment: @Rowland - now, if flickr would make collections shareable, that would make them significantly more useful.

Comment: @bill what do you mean by "shareable"? You can always send the link out

Comment: @Rowland, i mean to be able to send a guest pass to someone for a collection. http://flickr.com/groups/flickrideas/discuss/72157600044271250

Answer (score 5):

[SmugMug](http://www.smugmug.com) allows for what is essentially three levels:

```
Categories
--Subcategories
----Galleries
```

You can completely customize the names of Categories, Subcategories, and Galleries.